# Android take screenshot command - since which android version?

Tags: android, version, screenshot

I take a screenshot with root access and the command *screencap* located at /system/bin/screencap

Question: Which android versions do /system/bin/screencap have? It works on ICS for me and i want to know for which android versions i can publish my app.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/88a5df93668cb2079d10fd55de25a333f5f43842#diff-7f01b3c71f03ea738aadc95cf9d5d8f6): first tag for `cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp` set as `android-3.2.4_r1` then this tool firstly appear in `Android 3.2.4 release 1`.

But I should note that not all options of this utility was available immediately. Therefore, you'd better see the [history of code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commits/master/cmds/screencap/screencap.cpp) to learn exactly what versions are supported options you need.

For example:

- save as png [available](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/5cff0630eb970faf1682095ca434b204628b4d62#diff-7f01b3c71f03ea738aadc95cf9d5d8f6) from `android-3.2.4_r1`.
- Option `-d` [available](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/0b722fe9ce98d97dbcb6fefd170b85ab7037e528#diff-7f01b3c71f03ea738aadc95cf9d5d8f6) from `android-4.2.1_r1`.

Another note: in the custom firmware this command may not be. It is simply the application in `/system/bin/` and it may be absent.